# Flow not exiting like expected

Tags: spring-integration

new to SI. I have this SI Flow below. I would expect the Java program to exit when done, after the outbound channel, but it continues waiting, and I'm confused as to why. Thanks in advance!

```
<int-file:inbound-channel-adapter id="filesIn" 
directory="file:${com.cld.creditexpenses.inputdirectory}" 
    filename-pattern="*.313" auto-startup="true">
    <int:poller id="poller" fixed-delay="10000"/>
 </int-file:inbound-channel-adapter>   
      <int:service-activator  input-channel="filesIn" ref="delimitedFileProcessor" 
  method="processFile" output-channel="outChannel" />
        <int:outbound-channel-adapter id="outChannel" ref="fileArchiver" method="archiveFile" >
  </int:outbound-channel-adapter>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to close the application context when processing is complete, or replace the default `taskScheduler` with one that uses daemon threads - see [the documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/reference/html/configuration.html#namespace-taskscheduler).

But doing that means the program may exit before processing is complete - so you need to keep it running some other way.

Comment: Thanks for replying Gary. So if I'm running it using a Spring Boot class like below, I guess I need to change it somehow to get the application context and close it?

Comment: '@ImportResource("classpath:si-config.xml")
@SpringBootApplication
public class CreditExpensesApplication {

 public static void main(String[] args) {
  SpringApplication.run(CreditExpensesApplication.class, args);
 }
}'

Comment: Don't put code in comments; edit the question instead; as you can see, it's quite unreadable. The `run` method on `SpringApplication` returns the context. You will need some mechanism to know when the processing is complete; then close the context. `ConfigurableApplicationContext context = SpringApplication.run(...);`

Comment: Thanks Gary, but it's driving me crazy that I can't do this with just the XML config. I guess I don't understand why this example starts and stops, but mine is continuous. http://javarticles.com/2015/05/spring-integration-file-adapter-example.html

Comment: I guess see where he closes the context. Still driving me crazy.

Comment: I guess this more a fit with Spring Batch.

Comment: This is really intended to be long running - monitoring the directory and sending a message each time a new file arrives. You don't have to run it that way, though, you can simply create a `FileReadingMessageSource` and call `receive()` yourself (until it returns null) and send the resulting files to the outbound adapter using a `MessagingTemplate` or Messaging Gateway.

Comment: Thanks Gary. Sounds like a plan.